# Blurriness on different monitors

Tags: lcd

I have an IBM/Lenovo Thinkpad (X61s) laptop that seems to produce a blurry* screen on several monitors. I have used different cables, so it's either the laptop itself or perhaps both monitors have the same property. It appears to be a result of LCD screens - I hooked up an LED screen and the same thing did not happen.

Here is a link to the laptop specs:

http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/documents/pd012148

Here is the monitor:

http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c01869172&cc=us&dlc=en&lc=en

Any idea what this could be caused by and how to fix it?

*it appears as though everything (text, images, etc) have been smudged to the right a few pixels from their expected position on the screen.

Comment: The question is not on topic here, maybe it can be migrated. I think it may have to do with the phase setup of the monitor, there should be a button "auto"-something that makes the monitor sync the signal to the physical pixels.

Comment: An "LED screen" is just a LCD screen with a LED backlight instead of a CCFL.

Comment: Check the native resolution of each monitor and try to set the laptop to the same resolution.

Answer (score 1):

The web page of the monitor you link to states:

> Support for HDCP enables the monitor to display HDTV resolution if connected by the DVI connector. A monitor without HDCP support, or connected by analog VGA, causes the displayed video to be downgraded in quality to a DVD-like resolution that is less than HDTV.

Besides from this questionable statement it also says that it has a physical resolution of 1920 x 1080. Always set the laptop to the physical resolution for best viewing.